# r- Does anyone knows why my sorting isn't working well?

Tags: r

I was asked to combine chars and numbers in the same vector and sort it from high to low and the opposite.
somehow my first(and lowest) number get mixed up and jumps to the top(as the higher number)

```
library(ggplot2)
names<- c("E.coli","Chicken","Humans","Water flea","Rice")
organism_numbers <-c(4401,20345,20500,31000,40000)
organism_gene_numbers <- c(organism_numbers,names)

sort(organism_gene_numbers[1:5])
sort(organism_gene_numbers[1:5],TRUE)
```

```
> sort(organism_gene_numbers[1:5])
[1] "20345" "20500" "31000" "40000" "4401" 
> sort(organism_gene_numbers[1:5],TRUE)
[1] "4401"  "40000" "31000" "20500" "20345"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order the numbers as numeric you need to set them as numeric first, then sort them

```
> sort(as.numeric(organism_gene_numbers[1:5]))
[1]  4401 20345 20500 31000 40000
> sort(as.numeric(organism_gene_numbers[1:5]),TRUE)
[1] 40000 31000 20500 20345  4401
```

Otherwise, they will be sorted as string of characters